# Error in Java Program: "Move initializer to constructor"

Tags: java, swing, runnable, invokelater, awt-eventqueue

Where it starts `java.awt` and `public void run()`, they are both underlined in red and when I click on them with my mouse, I get a message that says to move initializer to constructor. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    EmployeeRecord main = new EmployeeRecord() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EmployeeRecord().setVisible(true);
            }
        )}
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve, thanks for the changes. I tried them and it didn't help.  I have the correct brackets further down in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the wrapper.  Below is all you need.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new EmployeeRecord().setVisible(true);
        }
    });    // <======= Notice the change here too. 
}
```

You just need to staticly call the method `invokeLater` of the `EventQueue` class. Doing what you're doing is a whole different (illegal) construct, which is not even possible. You are basically creating an anonymous class instance and in it you are calling the same constructor. Even if it was a *correct* construct like

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    EmployeeRecord main = new EmployeeRecord() {
        {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new EmployeeRecord().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

you'd be creating an unnecessary instance.